# Recursive UITableViewController and delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a `UITableViewController` that will recursively call itself n times:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        // call different controller
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        GroupTableViewController *tableView = [[GroupTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        tableView.delegate = self;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableView animated:TRUE];
    }
}
```

I need to set the new `GroupTableViewController`'s delegate to the current `GroupTableViewController`.

If I try to set the delegate as in the code, I get a warning:

```
Assigning to `id<GroupTableViewDelegate>' from incompatiable type `GroupTableViewController *const_strong`
```

So my first thought was to include the `GroupTableViewDelegate` protocol:

```
@interface GroupTableViewController : UITableViewController <RegionTableViewDelegate, GroupTableViewDelegate>
```

But this causes a warning:

```
Cannot find protocal definition for `GroupTableViewDelegate`
```

But if I try to

```
#import "GroupTableViewController.h"
```

thats gonna cause issues.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little confused -

```
        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

here `tableView` is a pointer to a `UITableView` instance

```
GroupTableViewController *tableView = 
  [[GroupTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

here `tableView` is a pointer to a GroupTableViewController instance

you should rename this one for clarity:

```
GroupTableViewController *gtViewController = 
  [[GroupTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Then your error should become evident.

This:

```
    tableView.delegate = self;
```

renamed is this:

```
   gtViewController.delegate = self;
```

when what you really want is:

```
   gtViewController.tableView.delegate = self;
```

No need to mess with additional protocol and delegate declarations...

Comment: Ok, I renamed the Controller, unfortunately it did not solve the warnings. Still have them.

Comment: @Log139, did you also change `controller.delegate=self` to `controller.tableView.delegate=self`?

Comment: Ugh, I did not. I apologize for not reading your full post. I glanced over it and thought I knew what to do. Clearly I did not. Thank you, that did clear up the warnings.